# Cosmos DB NOSQL Join Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have two containers in NOSQL Cosmos DB. One contains product details and another one contains all discount details based on sku or brand or account.

Below is my sample query.

```
SELECT p.sku, c.itemKey, c.priority, c.discountDetails
FROM c
JOIN p IN 
(
    SELECT VALUE [ 
        { sku: 'P001', account: 'account001', brand: 'NOKIA' },
        { sku: 'P002', account: 'account001', brand: 'NOKIA' },
        { sku: 'P003', account: 'account001', brand: 'NOKIA' },
        { sku: 'P004', account: 'account001', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P005', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P006', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P007', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P008', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P009', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P010', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P011', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P012', account: 'account002', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P013', account: 'account001', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P014', account: 'account001', brand: 'APPLE' },
        { sku: 'P015', account: 'account001', brand: 'SAMSUNG' },
        { sku: 'P016', account: 'account003', brand: 'SAMSUNG' },
        { sku: 'P017', account: 'account003', brand: 'SAMSUNG' },
        { sku: 'P018', account: 'account003', brand: 'SAMSUNG' },
        { sku: 'P019', account: 'account003', brand: 'SAMSUNG' }
        { sku: 'P020', account: 'account003', brand: 'SAMSUNG' }        
    ]
)
WHERE 
(
       c.itemKeyValue = CONCAT('_SKU_', p.sku)
    OR c.itemKeyValue = CONCAT('_BRAND_', p.brand)
    OR c.itemKeyValue = CONCAT('_ACC_', p.account)   
)
 
ORDER by c.priority asc, c.fromDate asc, c.toDate asc
```

There will be around 100 000 data in discount container. First I am getting all products in single query, prepare this json and then passing it join with discount container.

I need to get discount for lowest priority for each product in single query. Means for 20 product, I should get only 20 rows which have lowest priority per product. How can I achieve that?

Right now when I ran this query, as per stats, it is taking around 28MB as "Retrieved Document Size". Why it is taking this much of retrieving size? Is it because of join?

Comment: Simple answer: You cannot perform joins across containers. You can only execute a `JOIN` against the same document (e.g. joining some outer part of the document with each array element in an inner part). You'll need to run multiple queries (one to retrieve data from one container, then one to apply the data from the first query to the second query/container). Alternatively, you could create a *materialized view* to reduce the number of queries (but that's out of the scope of your question)